# What is maximum supported RAM for Snapdragon 410?

Tags: processor

Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 datasheet says:

> Memory
>   + LPDDR2/LPDDR3@533MHz
>   + eMMC 4.5
>   + SD 3.0 (UHS-I)

It does not talk about maximum amount of RAM supported. What is the maximum amoount of RAM this processor supports?

Comment: How many external address and data lines does it have?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams [this](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/snapdragon-410-processor-product-brief.pdf) is the source, but I don't find external address and data lines info in it.

Comment: Stop looking at briefs and start reading datasheets.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, [the datasheet](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sd410/snapdragon-410-processor-device-specification.pdf) also has not addressed maximum memory. It has just discussed read/write timing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2GB is the answer. Look at the memory map. For future reference, there's always 2 datasheets. One is for Electrical Characteristics the other is for Processor Characteristics. The bigger one is always the processor one and it always has all the info.

- [Hardware Register Description, Qualcomm Snapdragon 410 Processor (APQ 8016)](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/sd410/hardware-register-description-qualcomm-snapdragon-410.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't find 2GB in the sheet you attached.

Comment: Page 13, Figure 1-1. DDR is from 0x80000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF. Check the manual further for supported configurations and widths, but total addressable amount is 2GB/16Gb.

Comment: @KrunalDesai, excuse me, wouldn't total memory be 4 GB? What do you mean by 16Gb?

Comment: @JasonStack, 16Gb =  16 Gibi-bits. At 8 bits per byte means that 16Gb = 2GB = 2 Gibi-bytes.